# Compile AS3 text to executable code inside a Air App?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, ane

**GOAL** : I want to create a free educational tool that will allow you to write code and execute in the same app. ( preferably AS3 )

Essentially I want to be able to have a IDE written inside an Air Application and then run the code / execute inside the same application.

I'm not looking to create external files all i need is to run/execute the code from the text field. I was wondering if it's possible to use @mxmlc inside Air to do live coding.

Or perhaps any ANE's or native Android methods to archive the same goal. ( im assuming if it's possible to archive with android native code, then an ANE could be easily created )

Also i though maybe creating a limited library of all the essential Flash display library - so once i hit **run** in the Air app it will scan all the source code, and using a string search algorithm -> execute a list of precompiled classes inside the same app ( graphics API, display List, basic math logic, etc. ). I understand that method doesn't have to specifically target the AS3 language. But i would like to avoid creating my own language for that purpose.

Not familiar with mxmlc but i did read somewhere that it's possible to execute code on a server with maven. In that case would it be possible to send the user written source code to the server, receive back the compiled SWF file and upload it back to the app in the run-time ?

Comment: The compiler is just a Java program. Also see wonderfl.net

Comment: It's possible but compilation cannot be avoided.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without creating the necessary .as files. So compilation straight from a Textfield is probably impossible, but I would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: @HITMAN I like your : "... but unfortunately, I can't explain how because that is one of my biggest secrets.no one explains his big secret methods". May be the OP is ready to make an arrangement ($$$) ;)

Comment: Sounds g☺☺d ! I'm making the proof ready(making sure that isn't decompilable)you can give your email address and see the proof.and maybe "make an arrangement ($$$) " !

Comment: @DodgerThud loved this to be proven wrong and I just proved it !

Answer (score 0):

You could look at http://eval.hurlant.com/ http://eval.hurlant.com/demo/ but I'm not sure if it'll be working in Air / Android